# MPI Gather only gathering from Root Process

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

First off, I've been using [this code](https://www.msi.umn.edu/workshops/mpi/hands-on/data-movement/gather-scatter/solution-c) as a reference, which shows the use of `MPI_Gather` without `MPI_Scatter` as that is what I am trying to achieve here. I've been working on this for a long time now and just can't figure out the issue. This sobel edge detection algorithm strengthens the outlines of objects inside images.

I will post my code below, as there is not too much, but I'll give a quick code description first.

I am trying to convert a sequential program into a parallel program. So all the non-MPI code is correct.

So there can only be a mistake with my `MPI` code somewhere.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

     FILE *inFile, *oFile;
     int grayImage[N][N], edgeImage[N][N];
     char type[2];
     int w, h, max;
     int r, g, b, y, x, i, j, sum, sumx, sumy;
     int tid;

     int GX[3][3], GY[3][3];
     double elapsed_time;
     struct timeval tv1, tv2;
     int error = 0;
     char buffer[BUFSIZ];
     int rank, NP;

     // Code lies here for reading from the image file and storing into the grayImage array. 
     // This works so I saw no reason to include it

     /* 3x3 Sobel masks. */
     GX[0][0] = -1; GX[0][1] = 0; GX[0][2] = 1;
     GX[1][0] = -2; GX[1][1] = 0; GX[1][2] = 2;
     GX[2][0] = -1; GX[2][1] = 0; GX[2][2] = 1;

     GY[0][0] =  1; GY[0][1] =  2; GY[0][2] =  1;
     GY[1][0] =  0; GY[1][1] =  0; GY[1][2] =  0;
     GY[2][0] = -1; GY[2][1] = -2; GY[2][2] = -1;



     MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NP);
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

     // This calculates the block size.MPI 
     // On 4 processors the block size for a 100x100 image would be 25x100 each

     int blksz = (int)ceil((double)N/NP);

     // This creates a local array for each processor, soon to be gathered

     int tempEdge[blksz][N];

     // this line shows it's working correctly

     printf("processor %d, width: %d, height: %d, blksz: %d, begin: %d, end: %d\n", rank, w, h, blksz, rank*blksz, (rank+1)*blksz);

     for(x=rank*blksz; x < (rank+1)*blksz && x<h; x++){

        // Any code in this loop can be ignored as it works correctly.

         for(y=0; y < w; ++y){

             sumx = 0;
             sumy = 0;
             // handle image boundaries 
             if(x==0 || x==(h-1) || y==0 || y==(w-1))
                 sum = 0;
             else{
                 //x gradient approx
                 for(i=-1; i<=1; i++)  {
                     for(j=-1; j<=1; j++){
                         sumx += (grayImage[x+i][y+j] * GX[i+1][j+1]);
                     }
                 }
                 //y gradient approx
                 for(i=-1; i<=1; i++)  {
                     for(j=-1; j<=1; j++){
                         sumy += (grayImage[x+i][y+j] * GY[i+1][j+1]);
                     }
                 }
                 //gradient magnitude approx
                 sum = (abs(sumx) + abs(sumy));
             }
             tempEdge[x][y] = clamp(sum);
         }
     }

     // Here is the line I am guessing is causing the problem

     MPI_Gather(&tempEdge, w*blksz, MPI_INT,
               &edgeImage, w*blksz, MPI_INT, 0,
               MPI_COMM_WORLD);


     // Finally, I output edgeImage to a file here.

     if(rank==0){

         // output edgeImage to File

     }

     MPI_Finalize();

     return 0;    
}
```

The input image I am using is this:

[image]

But the output is only giving this:

[image]

As you can see it is only the top quarter (N/4), or `blksz` of the image.

This would imply that `MPI_Gather` is only gathering from process with rank 0?

I've been spending so much time on this, any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not blame MPI collectives for bugs in the rest of your code. It is actually a miracle that your code produces broken images without segfaulting. Just take a look at that part:

```
int tempEdge[blksz][N];
             ~~~~~

for(x = rank*blksz; x < (rank+1)*blksz && x<h; x++){
        ~~~~~~~~~~
   for(y = 0; y < w; ++y){
      ...
      tempEdge[x][y] = clamp(sum);    (1)
               ~
   }
}
```

For any rank > 0 the code writes past the end of the array. Fix the statement at (1) to read:

```
tempEdge[x - rank*blksz][y] = clamp(sum);
```

Also, remove the `&`s in the `MPI_Gather` call:

```
MPI_Gather(tempEdge, w*blksz, MPI_INT,
           edgeImage, w*blksz, MPI_INT, 0,
           MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

It will work with `&` too, but that is technically incorrect. If you insist on using the *address-of* operator, then use `&tempEdge[0][0]` and `&edgeImage[0][0]` instead.

Comment: I actually can't believe I missed that! Now I feel dumb for posting this on SO. Thank you so much for looking through all that code!

Comment: I know, debugging MPI code is hard as one can count the number of usable parallel debuggers on the fingers of one hand and most of them are commercial.